# Automatically divide by how many projects are used to get value

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a main sheet and 10 other sheets each with one of my projects. Right now I'm taking values only from 3 of them and the other ones are empty.

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE('Project 1'!B2, 'Project 2'!B2, 'Project 3'!B2, 'Project 4'!B2, 'Project 5'!B2, 'Project 6'!B2, 'Project 7'!B2, 'Project 8'!B2, 'Project 9'!B2, 'Project 10'!B2 ) / 3)`

I divide my `/3` because the rest of the projects are empty. Is there a way to automatically figure out by how much should I divide it? So if I had 5 projects filled with data, it would automatically divide by 5 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COUNTA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991) to get the number of values in a data set

**Sample:**

```
=COUNTA('Project 1'!B2, 'Project 2'!B2, 'Project 3'!B2, 'Project 4'!B2, 'Project 5'!B2, 'Project 6'!B2, 'Project 7'!B2, 'Project 8'!B2, 'Project 9'!B2, 'Project 10'!B2 )
```

Should return 5, if only 5 projects has non-empty values.

**Complete Formula:**

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE('Project 1'!B2, 'Project 2'!B2, 'Project 3'!B2, 'Project 4'!B2, 'Project 5'!B2, 'Project 6'!B2, 'Project 7'!B2, 'Project 8'!B2, 'Project 9'!B2, 'Project 10'!B2 ) / COUNTA('Project 1'!B2, 'Project 2'!B2, 'Project 3'!B2, 'Project 4'!B2, 'Project 5'!B2, 'Project 6'!B2, 'Project 7'!B2, 'Project 8'!B2, 'Project 9'!B2, 'Project 10'!B2 ))
```

**Note:**

- I'm not sure if you're goal is to take the average of your non-empty projects since you want to determine the count of non-empty projects. You might need to use SUM() instead of AVERAGE() in your dividend

if your goal is to take the average of non-empty projects, you can consider using this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY({'Project 1'!B2, 'Project 2'!B2, 'Project 3'!B2, 'Project 4'!B2, 'Project 5'!B2, 'Project 6'!B2, 'Project 7'!B2, 'Project 8'!B2, 'Project 9'!B2, 'Project 10'!B2 },"where Col1 is not null"))
```

- the query() will return all non-empty values from the listed data set. Then use average().

Answer (score 0):

This script will do the entire calculation:

All sheets that contain the string 'Project' and that have a value in B2 will be used in the average calculation.

```
function projavg() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const name = 'Project';//Sheets that contain this string will be considered if they have a value in B2
  const avg = ss.getSheets().reduce((a, c) => { if (~c.getName().indexOf(name) && c.getRange('B2').getValue()) { a.sum += c.getRange('B2').getValue(); a.n++; } return a; }, { n: 0, sum: 0, avg: function () { return this.sum / this.n; } }).avg();
  Logger.log(avg);
}
```